# Why is a diagonal scattering matrix preferable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Maybe it is a trivial question, but it is not so clear to me why (if it is so) I would rather want a diagonal S-Matrix.
Thanks

Comment: Being diagonal isn’t an invariant property of a matrix. Did you mean diagonalizable?

Comment: No, sorry, I give you some background. I'm dealing with 2D integrable models with one degree of freedom. On the s-matrix diagonal there are S++ -> ++ (-- ->--) and + - -> +-. The off-diagonal element is the reflection one +- -> -+ : I am studying the regime for which the reflection amplitude is zero, so that the s matrix becomes diagonal. I don't really understand what consequences one may enjoy from this

Comment: I think you should include that in your question, and also provide all details on what $+$ and $-$ indices mean in your notation. Which integrable system are you studying? Could you provide references?